# Send more values via URL

Tags: javascript, datatable

I am using Datatable  plug-in to print values from database. 
I get results and it prints in table. Now I am having trouble with sending values to the other file. Values that I need to send are userID, all titles of column except for last title, and two other variables which contains date.

When I click on '', beside data that contains userId, I need to send "User, Work time, Additions, Business, Break" as well as two variables printed below.

Other two variables are:

var date1 = "2017-01-01";
var date2 = "2017-02-28";

```
$('#myData').DataTable( { 
    data: dataSet, 
    fixedHeader: true,
    responsive: true,       
    "columns": [
        { title: "User", data: "ime"},
        { title: "Work time", data: "Rad" },
        { title: "Additions", data: "Privatno" },
        { title: "Business", data: "Poslovno" }, 
        { title: "Break", data: "Pauza" }, 
        {
            "title": '<i class="icon-file-plus"></i>',
            "data": "userID",  
            "render": function (data) {
                return '<a href="preview.php?id=' + data + '">' + '<i class="icon-file-plus"></i>' + '</a>';
            }, "width": "1%",
        }

    ]
    ,"columnDefs": [ { "defaultContent": "-", "targets": "_all" },{ className: "dt-body-center", "targets": [ 5 ] } ]
});
```

Any help or advice is appreciated, I am stuck here.

Comment: From the code you provided it is not clear where the issue is. Show us your click listener/data sending code